# Swipe container never stop refreshing android

Tags: listview, refresh, swiperefreshlayout

Here is my stupid code, I want finish refreshing when I updated listview.

```
 @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listHistory.refreshDrawableState();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: you got answer to this ??

Answer (score 0):

I think that You would try putting listHistory.refreshDrawableState(); and 
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); above the handler.